# Problems with JSON file

Tags: python, json, string, list, variables

I'm making a code which is randomly picking information from a JSON file and putting it into an applescript display notification. And can run through the terminal

I would like to make three different lists in my JSON file that all link to there one thing: random_name, random_sentence, random_sub instead of having one list and picking all the words only from that one.

How can I do this? Should I do this with making a dictionary? Variables? Making other JSON files?

Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import random
import subprocess

def randomLine():
    jsonfile = "sentences.json"
    with open(jsonfile) as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)

    # print len(data)
    return random.choice(data)

def executeShell(notif_string, notif_title, notif_subtitle):
    applescript = 'display notification "%s" with title "%s" subtitle "%s"' % (notif_string, notif_title, notif_subtitle)
    subprocess.call(["osascript", "-e", applescript])

def main():
    random_name = randomLine()
    random_zin = randomLine()
    random_sub = randomLine()
    executeShell(random_name, random_zin, random_sub)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

JSON file:

```
[
    "one",
    "two", 
    "three", 
    "four", 
    "five",
    "six"
]
```

Comment: Well I don't understand. What do you want to do? What's the expect output? Can you give us a [mcve] please?

Comment: With this code all the strings pick random words from one list in the JSON file such "one", "two", "three". I would love to have separate lists in my JSON file that link with the strings in my python file. That for example the first string picks the words randomly from the list with “one”, “two, “three” and the second string chooses randomly from another list with for example: “aa”, “bb”, “cc”.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. `json.load()` returns a dictionary, so you can just run `random.choice()` over it :

```
import json
import random
import subprocess

jsonfile = "sentences.json"

def main():
    with open(jsonfile, "r") as file:
        # You might want to add a sanity check here, file might be malformed
        data = json.load(file)

    random_name = random.choice(data["name"])
    random_zin = random.choice(data["zin"])
    random_sub = random.choice(data["sub"])
    subprocess.call(["osascript", "-e", "display notification \
        '{0}' with title '{1}' \
        subtitle '{2}'".format(random_name, random_zin, random_sub)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Your original JSON file only contained one list of strings. Here's one with 3 different lists, named "name", "zin" & "sub" :

```
{
    "name":[
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
     ],
     "zin":[
        "four",
        "five",
        "six"
     ],
     "sub":[
        "seven",
        "eight",
        "nine"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should note the problem with the original JSON file I am saying for your answer to be useful you should note in your answer the issue with the JSON file

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! Maybe I'm doing something wrong but it is saying: execution error: The variable two is not defined. Do you know what I can do to fix this? @s0r00t

Comment: I'm not on OS X, but you might want to add quotes over the formatting strings ({0}...) in `subprocess.call()`. Edited my answer, the code should work.